# Перенос кода с Windows Python Selenium на Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, selenium

Есть код на Python с использованием Selenium, работающим на Windows.
Код - многопоточный бот смотрящий рекламу за денежное вознаграждение, со всеми особенностями user-agent и сменой ip.
Встал вопрос: Возможно ли реализовать подобное на смартфоне с Android?

1. Создание временного профиля браузера в WebViewClient
2. Включение/выключение авиарежима - для смены ip на мобильном трафике (Про это читал, что Google ограничил возможность подобных действий с настройками телефона, но может быть есть другое решение с автоматизацией)
3. Считывание json файла выбранного пользователем, где будут данные пользователей для бота

Хочу попробовать реализовать сначала на одном устройстве, а далее по увеличении вознаграждений покупать ещё смартфоны. Чисто экономия места и мобильность

Comment: [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/), помимо него есть различные программы по автоматизации, где как в no-code из блоков собираешь, для них root нужен. Но, ИМХО, лучше разобраться как это не на Selenium делать, тогда одной машины для масшстабируемости хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Для создания приложения под андройд написанного на python3 нужно использовать фреймворки Kivy и KivyMD.

После того как приложение написано используйте сборщик установочных пакетов .apk под названием buildozer 1.2.0 (самая нормальная версия).

Кстати buildozer существует только под линукс.